# Read a 16 Bit Bitmap in Java

Tags: java, bitmap, javax.imageio

I need to read a 16 Bit Bitmap (R5 G6 B5) with java in eclipse. I tried it with ImageIO.read(), but i get an error:
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)

The same code works without problems with a 24 Bit Bitmap.

```
File file = new File("D:/MainScreen16BitR5G6B5.bmp");
imgBuf = ImageIO.read(file);
```

Is there an other way then ImageIO.read() for that case? Or some special library?
I searched for a solution but I didn't found one. Only for tiff's or how to convert to 16 Bit.

All tips are welcome! Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `I need to read a 16 Bit Bitmap (R5 G6 B5) with java in eclipse.` Please note that Eclipse is just an IDE, a tool that you use to write your code. It does not affect your code, so _in eclipse_ your program will run the same way it would _out of eclipse_ :)

Comment: Also be sure that your file exists and is actually a valid 16-bit BMP. And it would be helpful if you told us what version of the JDK you are using.

Comment: It seems unlinkely that ImageIO can read such a "special" format (although I do *not* know this for sure). You might want to give http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html a try, there you'll have different new image reader implementations.

Comment: What is `imgBuf` defined as? Also, there's a good chance your filename should be more like `D:\\MainScreen16BitR5G6B5.bmp`

Comment: @Marco13 It didn't used to be able to read 16-bit bitmaps but I believe support was added at some point in the past few years, although I have no concrete source for either points. Anyways the error message and `ImageIO.java` source line show that it's actually a file I/O error, not a format error (which may come next if the 16-bit format *isn't* supported, but we haven't gotten to that point yet).

Comment: @EvanKnowles "D:/filename" and "D:\\filename" will both be treated the same on Windows, which recognizes "/" as a valid path separator. Also no matter what `imgBuf` is, the fact that it compiled (and thus produced the described error) means that it can at least hold a `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to be related to the format of the bitmap. Your error message has two hints:

1. The exception text is "Can't read input file!".
2. The exception source is `ImageIO.java` line 1301.

Presuming you are using Java 7, if we take a look at the [`ImageIO` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java?av=f), we can see that the relevant code, matching your description, in `ImageIO.read()` is:

```
public static BufferedImage read(File input) throws IOException {
    ...
    if (!input.canRead()) {
        throw new IIOException("Can't read input file!");   // <- line 1301
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that `input` is a `File` and this implies that `File#canRead()` is returning `false` for your image. Looking at the documentation for [`File#canRead()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead()), we see that it:

> **Returns:** `true` if and only if the file specified by this abstract pathname exists and can be read by the application; `false` otherwise.

**TL;DR:**

Therefore we can conclude that the *real* problem is either that **the file does not exist, or you do not have permission to read it**, rather than a problem with the file format.

So check to make sure your path names are correct and that the file actually does exist, and that your application has permission to read it. This should always be the first thing you check when you encounter errors such as this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested it with file.exist and file.canRead. It was my fault, I had a typo in the filename :-/